Can I use ceramics instead of electrolytic capacitors in CRT drive circuit?
I've been recapping an Amstrad PCW 9256 computer.
All the electrotyics are bad on the analogue board - I've replaced the electrolytics I have in stock and the CRT is now working almost perfectly but there is still a bit of 'jittering'.
There are some high voltage, low capacitance capacitors that make up part of the CRT drive circuit:

22uF 63V (C801)
1uF 160V (C426)
10uF 160V (C427)

Could any/all of these be replaced by ceramic capacitors?  I have a few of these in stock.
Also keen to understand why is ok/not ok in this application.
Schematic section attached with capacitors in question highlighted on it:


I am so impressed! Good work so far. I think I would also replace the three capacitors you mentioned. And yes, if you have ceramics at those magnitudes of value (do you?) then the only question I have is "what type of ceramic and how voltage-dependent are they?" I'll +1 the question.

Do you know the exact part numbers and properties for the capacitors? Based on just the schematics, all you know is that they appear to be polarized, likely aluminium electrolytics based on symbol, and the capacitance and voltage. There are also other electrolytics like tantalums, but unlikely here. But there is no knowledge of temperature rating or ESR. If you replace a regular electrolytic with a capacitor with much different properties like ESR, it may lead to less ripple which is good, but also higher pulsed currents and it may make a cicuit unstable (phase shift etc is different).

I dont know full spec, they are aluminium electrolytics made by rubycon and date back to about 1992.

Hmm, bit embarrasing! Double checked my cap stash and I had mis-converted my powers of 10!
So you were right to be skeptical of what I had!
Were 100nF not 1000nF, so if have to buy a load of new electrolytics anyway, will just buy the 3 above!
Sorry!!

How do you determine the caps are ‘bad’? Rarely do I come across equipment that need all their electrolytic capacitors changed. The concept of ‘recapping’ is a bit of a fad methinks.

Because it didn't work initially. Touching the caps would cause the distortion on the image to change. With each capacitor replacement, the image would normalise. Many of the capacitors had evidence of electrolyte leakage underneath. Testing them out of circuit showed them to be well our of spec. So, in summary, replacing them (and no other changes) fixed the issue and the removed capacitors tested bad and showed evidence of leakage

Doubtful: ceramics are most effective for such values in low voltages (1-20V say).  Even then, say towards the upper end of that range, the C(V) curves are pretty steep, and a typical e.g. 10uF 50V X7R 1206 is -70%:

From: CL31B106KBHNNN# | MLCC | Product Search | SAMSUNG ELECTRO-MECHANICS
Somewhat larger chips are available (1210, 1812, 2220..), but cost goes up rapidly beyond 1210 (as well as issues with cracking caused by board strain and temperature cycling), and the C(V) curve tends to be even steeper in higher voltage ratings -- more or less because they can make the dielectric a little bit thicker, which makes it much more reliable (free from pinhole defects), so can handle more voltage before breakdown.
Key takeaway: the voltage rating of a ceramic capacitor is its withstand value.  The rating bears no relation to the actual useful capacitance range of the part; for that, you have to look up the C(V) curve, and tolerance, aging, etc.
Note: this is specific to type 2 dielectric (high capacity) types (X7R, Z5U, etc.).
Type 1 (C0G/NP0, SL, etc.) are essentially independent of voltage, and have specified tempco; in many ways they actually approach an ideal capacitor (well, C0G; the others, give or take your feeling on how ideal a tempco is, heh).  They just happen to be expensive to make in large values.
There are also capacitor assemblies available that package several chips into a lead frame, solving several issues at once: utilization of space (it's not limited to a single chip-height package on the PCB), lead flex / strain relief (the lead frame provides mechanical compliance), much larger total value; but they also tend to be very expensive, and I'm guessing you don't have many in your inventory (but, if you do, and you have the characteristic sheets to check C(V) if applicable -- yeah, that's definitely an option!).
As for the circuit, the main thing to look out for is whether ESR matters.  Electrolytics contain a fairly generous amount by default, and this is often used to advantage in circuit.  Ceramics contain very little, and can behave in unexpected or surprising ways as a result.
Of the three parts mentioned:

C801: bypass/filter cap for video amp. Supplied by resistors, no other capacitors connected (well, maybe the zeners' junction capacitance?).  ESR irrelevant, could be high or low (mΩ to low Ω), just as long as it's not completely wheezed out.
(Dry electrolytics reduce in value, and increase exponentially in ESR.  I suppose a failing part here could result in visible "drool" on the display (streaking to the right of graphics, or glow or fade from left to right).)

C427: seems to be a DC-restore coupling capacitor.  It's between a supply (more on that below), and the first grid; there's a bleeder resistor (2 x 22M) supplying it, and a clamp diode ensuring grid voltage stays below, at most, a diode drop (about 0.7V).  ESR also very unimportant here; it just needs to take a charge once in a while, in relation to the discharge resistors.  Internal (self) leakage is a more important aspect probably (a leaky cap would draw more current than R438+R439 do, eventually doing something I suppose).

C426: this seems to be an ordinary "B+ boost" filter capacitor, taking a diode off a tap from the flyback, and making, evidently, +150V or so.  That seems fine, but the peculiar thing is, the ripple on this very supply is what's being coupled into the grid above.  For this to matter at all, the grid AC voltage surely must be some 10s of V.  The output current is evidently around 20mA, and the flyback duty cycle is maybe 5 or 10%, so the peak current, 200-400mA.  To even get 10V, this must be 25Ω or more ESR!  That seems suspiciously large to me, and I wonder if it was a selected type; even back in the day, that's a lot of ESR.
But I also wonder if the DC restore network is simply erroneous.  It doesn't make sense to be raising the grid voltage during retrace (flyback); it should be the other way around, but probably they just do H-blanking in the video signal itself, and the grid could be grounded.  Maybe there is another connection here (schematic error), or these components were forgotten, vestigial after other schematic changes (engineering error).  I don't know.  Or there's something else I don't know about the tube, unlikely but possible.


In any case, if you have enough ceramics to stack up and make such values under bias... yeah, you could.  Maybe add a resistor in series with ceramic-C426 just in case.  Film capacitors would be a bit more likely -- values this size are available, if not common in the larger values -- but might be too bulky to fit in circuit, and the same really goes for ceramics.

that's really helpful and understandable - thank you!
